# Angular Ag-Grid, how to place a material progress spinner inside of the overlayNoRowsTemplate?

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I am trying to place a mat-progress-spinner inside of my agGrid when there are no rows to show.

Something like this works:

```
private overlayNoRowsTemplate = '<p>No rows to show.</p>';
```

But when I try to add the mat-progress-spinner it doesn't show

```
private overlayNoRowsTemplate = '<mat-progress-spinner style="margin:0 auto;" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>'
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/

> ### Custom Templates
>
> If you're not happy with the provided overlay templates, you can provide your own. This is done with the grid properties
>   `overlayLoadingTemplate` and `overlayNoRowsTemplate`. These templates
>   should be **plain HTML**.

However, you can use an Angular component if you use a "custom overlay component" instead:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/

Answer (score 0):

My solution below doesn't use mat-spinner or any other dependencies, only .css.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-modules-forked-zpvv8z

styles.css add `.loader`

app.componenent.ts change: `public overlayLoadingTemplate = '<div class="loader" aria-label="loading"></div>';`